# RSA not worked prpoprely

Tags: android, android-studio

```
public static KeyPair NewPair() throws CertificateException {
    KeyPair two = null;
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGen.initialize(448);
        two = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
        byte[] buffer = two.getPublic().getEncoded();
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        passwd = getRandom().toCharArray();
```

Seems it RSA not generating anything. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count);
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA1AndDES");
        SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHA1AndDES");
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
        byte[] ciphertext = pbeCipher.doFinal(buffer);
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ciphertext);
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        passwd = getRandom().toCharArray();
```

This fixed!